# Setting the credentials for Google APIs in IntelliJ IDEA

Tags: java, spring-boot, google-cloud-platform, google-api, google-oauth

I open a terminal inside IntelliJ IDEA and run this:

```
export GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS="/Users/nunyito/IdeaProjects/mystic-river-api/src/main/resources/google-gemini/mysticriver.json"
```

I have this in the json file:

```
{
  "type": "service_account",
  "project_id": "mysticriver,
  "private_key_id": "c81d561c1z65159b925ddd7a00c895358855b855c",
  "private_key": "-----BEGIN PRIVATE KEY-----\nREDACTED\n-----END PRIVATE KEY-----\n",
  "client_email": "service-account-for-mystic-riv@mysticriver.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "client_id": "117167372461671003080",
  "auth_uri": "https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth",
  "token_uri": "https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token",
  "auth_provider_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs",
  "client_x509_cert_url": "https://www.googleapis.com/robot/v1/metadata/x509/service-account-for-mystic-riv%40mysticriver.iam.gserviceaccount.com",
  "universe_domain": "googleapis.com"
}
```

then I run this service:

```
@Service
public class GoogleGeminiService {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
       
        String projectId = "MysticRiver";
        String location = "us-central1";
        String modelName = "gemini-pro-vision";

        String output = simpleQuestion(projectId, location, modelName);
        System.out.println(output);
    }
}
```

but I have this error:

```
...context/6.1.1/spring-context-6.1.1.jar com.mysticriver.service.GoogleGeminiService
Exception in thread "main" java.io.IOException: Your default credentials were not found. To set up Application Default Credentials for your environment, see https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/external/set-up-adc.
    at com.google.auth.oauth2.DefaultCredentialsProvider.getDefaultCredentials(DefaultCredentialsProvider.java:127)
```

Comment: What sample are you following exactly why not use [java quickstart](https://ai.google.dev/tutorials/android_quickstart#java)

Comment: I see that the example is for Android, while i am using SpringBoot

Comment: I know its also for vertex I'm trying to find a  better version but I think the team is off for the holidays

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, a service account key file is a secret and YOU DO NOT HAVE TO SHARE IT. That's why I updated your question and redacted the content (I recommend you to destroy the key, it's safer).

Then, you don't need a key, it's not safe. It's a secret, you can too easily share it (like you did).

So, I recommend to use ADC with your own account (`gcloud auth application-default login`) or impersonation to use the service account permission ( add parameter `--impersonate-service-account=<SA email>`)

Because you use ADC in a safe way, your problem should be solved in the same time!